# With dplyr and enquo my code works but not when I pass to purrr::map

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, purrr, quosure

I want to create a plot for each column in a vector called dates. My data frame contains only these columns and I want to group on it, count the occurrences and then plot it.

Below code works, except for `map` which I want to use to go across a previously unknown number of columns. I think I'm using `map` correctly, I've had success with it before. I'm new to using quosures but given that my function call works I'm not sure what is wrong. I've looked at several other posts that appear to be set up this way.

```
df <- data.frame(
  date1 = c("2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-02","2018-01-02","2018-01-02"),
  date2 = c("2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-02","2018-01-02","2018-01-02"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
dates<-names(df)

library(tidyverse)

dates.count<-function(.x){
  group_by<-enquo(.x)
  df %>% group_by(!!group_by) %>% summarise(count=n()) %>% ungroup() %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(y=count,x=!!group_by))
}
dates.count(date1)
map(dates,~dates.count(.x))
```

I get this error: Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : Column `.x` is unknown

Comment: does `map(dates, dates.count)` work for you?

Comment: That does produce 2 plots but they're not correct. The x axis appears to be character (or discrete) with just the column name as the single axis break, rather than the dates on the axis.

Comment: At what point do you convert to a `Date` object? You might want to include `%>% mutate_at(vars(date1, date2), funs(as.Date(.)))` somewhere in your data generation/mangling.

Comment: In my real code and data the columns are date objects (dates is a vector that is composed of the names of only the date objects in the data frame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the variable names to `map()` you are using strings, which indicates you need `ensym()` instead of `enquo()`.

So your function would look like

```
dates.count <- function(.x){
    group_by = ensym(.x)
    df %>% 
        group_by(!!group_by) %>% 
        summarise(count=n()) %>% 
        ungroup() %>% 
        ggplot() + 
        geom_point(aes(y=count,x=!!group_by))
}
```

And you would use the variable names as strings for the argument.

```
dates.count("date2")
```

Note that tidyeval doesn't always play nicely with the formula interface of `map()` (I think I'm remembering that correctly).  You can always do an anonymous function instead, but in your case where you want to map the column names to a function with a single argument you can just do

```
map(dates, dates.count)
```

Using the formula interface in `map()` I needed an extra `!!`:

```
map(dates, ~dates.count(!!.x))
```

Comment: This works. I understand what you mean about variable names as strings-- I had tried using `sym` based on a different SO answer. What I don't understand is why using '~dates.count(.x)` does NOT work. Something about the need to unquote it requires a different syntax?